# How to use the dropwon selenium selector?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use the selenium selector but I'm still getting this error message.
When I try 3Select(web.find_element("id",'ticket-quantity-selector-756706789'))", it doesn't seem to work on my terminal.
Thank you

```
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response

-------------------------
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('https://www.eventbrite.fr/e/masquerade-party-tickets-443305678217')

time.sleep(5)

cookie = web.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="_evidon-accept-button"]')
cookie.click()

info = web.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-443305678217"]')
info.click()

CoupC = Select(web.find_element("id",'ticket-quantity-selector-756706789'))
CoupC.select_by_visible_text("5")

//*[@id="ticket-quantity-selector-756706789"]
CoupS = Select(web.find_element("id",'ticket-quantity-selector-756706799'))
CoupS.select_by_visible_text("5")

Cliquer = web.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button')
Cliquer.click()

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns are inside an iframe, so first you have to switch to iframe, then you have to select the option, try this, it's working:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element(By.ID, "eventbrite-widget-modal-443305678217")))

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID,'ticket-quantity-selector-756706789').click()
CoupC = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,'ticket-quantity-selector-756706789'))
CoupC.select_by_visible_text("5")

CoupS = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,'ticket-quantity-selector-756706799'))
CoupS.select_by_visible_text("5")

Cliquer = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button')
Cliquer.click()
```

If you need to switch to the main page from iframe, add this:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I received this error message : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ticket-quantity-selector-756706789"]"}
 What can I do ?

Comment: added some wait time and un-commented the click() action, try now.

Comment: Still the same error message